# Laplace transform of $u(x,t)\sin{x}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I am trying to work out what the Laplace transform of $u(x,t)\sin{x}$ is.

I have worked it out as $L(u(x,t)\sin{x})=U(x,s)\sin{x}$, where $L(u(x,t))=U(x,s)$, using definition:

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}f(x)dt$$

In one of the comments on [Solving $u_{t}+u_{xxx} = u\sin{x}$ using Laplace transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253763/solving-u-tu-xxx-u-sinx-using-laplace-transforms) , in a comment it is indicated that the Laplace transform of $u(x)\sin{x}$ is not $U(s)\sin{x}$.

Comment: You need to get your variables straight here: $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$. $U$, the Laplace transform of $u$ wrt $t$, is a function of $x$ and $s$. Functions only of $x$, like $\sin{x}$, do not depend on $t$ and so may be treated as constants when doing the Laplace transform with respect to $t$.

Comment: @chappers Exactly what I thought. So is my working right in my answer above?

Comment: Yes your answers is correct.